# Why AWS App runner can't connect to RDS Postgres database when it is publicly accessible?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-rds

I have a .Net 6 API for a mobile app and I want it to deploy on AWS App Runner. I containerized it with Docker and it is working fine locally, I can run it, migrations are working, also I can work on the database from pgAdmin but when I try to deploy the app, it says that the database is not found:

I get the error message "Health check failed" and the following occurs in the log.

```
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM       Content root path: /app
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM       Hosting environment: Production
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at API.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/API/Program.cs:line 28
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.UnpooledConnectorSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|195_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM          at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM        ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM       Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to 52.215.162.0:5432
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM       An error occured during migration
12-24-2022 09:10:17 PM [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: API.Program[0]
12-24-2022 09:10:02 PM       Entity Framework Core 6.0.12 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL:6.0.8+e68dfe8b5cbe4a26d20acc36def6187aa1cfdda3' with options: None
12-24-2022 09:10:02 PM [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
12-24-2022 09:09:39 PM       Application is shutting down...
12-24-2022 09:09:39 PM [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
12-24-2022 09:06:15 PM       Content root path: /app
12-24-2022 09:06:15 PM [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
12-24-2022 09:06:15 PM       Hosting environment: Production
12-24-2022 09:06:15 PM [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
12-24-2022 09:06:15 PM       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
12-24-2022 09:06:15 PM [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
12-24-2022 09:06:15 PM       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
12-24-2022 09:06:15 PM [40m[32minfo[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
```

Code to which error refers in Program.cs :

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

            try
            {
                var context =  services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                logger.LogError(ex, "An error occured during migration");
            }

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

Although, I think the solution is not in the API code and more likely something with the App Runner not having access to RDS. Someone can help with it, please?

Answer (score 0):

@Ujfalusi, Please check VPC connector's Security group outbound rules or Your database Security group inbound rules. Both SGs should allow vice versa traffic on require port.